# Firebase auth coming as null in nuxtjs middleware on page reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

New to nuxtjs. I'm using Nuxt firebase(https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/) library for firebase. On successfull login I'm redirecting user to "/member/desk" route. But, once redirecting to that particular page, if I refresh the page then I'm redirecting to "/auth/signin" page. It's because in "middleware/auth.js" file I'm not getting `app.$fire.auth.currentUser` value as `null`.

I Google this but didn't any reliable info which can fix my issue. Need some help.

Here are my files..

- nuxt.config.js

```
[
    '@nuxtjs/firebase',
    {
        config: {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: "",
            measurementId: ""
        },
        services: {
            auth: {
            persistence: 'local', // default
            initialize: {
                onAuthStateChangedAction: 'onAuthStateChangedAction',
                subscribeManually: false
            },
            ssr: false
            }
        }
    }
]
```

- store/index.js

```
const actions = {
    async onAuthStateChangedAction(state, { authUser, claims }) {
        if (!authUser) {
            // remove state
            state.commit('SET_USER', null)

            //redirect from here
            this.$router.push({
                path: '/auth/signin',
            })
        } else {
            // console.log('authUser', authUser);
            const { uid, email } = authUser
            state.commit('SET_USER', {
                uid,
                email,
            })
        }
    },
}

const mutations = {
    SET_USER(state, user) {
        state.user = user
    },
}

const state = () => ({
    user: null,
})

const getters = {
    getUser(state) {
        return state.user
    },
}

export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters,
}
```

- middleware/auth.js

```
export default function ({ store, app, route, redirect }) {
    if (route.path === '/') {
        //leave them on the sign in page
    } else if (route.path !== '/auth/signin') {
        //we are on a protected route
        console.log('app.$fire.auth', app.$fire.auth.currentUser);
        if (!app.$fire.auth.currentUser) {
            //take them to sign in page
            return redirect('/auth/signin')
            // return redirect('/auth/signout')
        }
    } else if (route.path === '/auth/signin') {
        if (!app.$fire.auth.currentUser) {
            //leave them on the sign in page
        } else {
            return redirect('/')
        }
    }
}
```

- pages/index.js

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="center" align="center">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="8" md="4">
      <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="email"
          :rules="emailRules"
          type="email"
          label="E-mail"
          autocomplete="username"
          required
        ></v-text-field>

        <v-text-field
          v-model="password"
          :rules="passwordRules"
          type="password"
          label="Password"
          autocomplete="current-password"
          required
        ></v-text-field>

        <v-btn :disabled="!valid" color="success" class="mr-4" @click="login">
          Login
        </v-btn>
      </v-form>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: "plain",
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    name: "",
    nameRules: [
      (v) => !!v || "Name is required",
      (v) => (v && v.length <= 10) || "Name must be less than 10 characters",
    ],
    password: "",
    passwordRules: [
      (v) => !!v || "Password is required",
      (v) => (v && v.length >= 6) || "Password must minimums 6 characters",
    ],
    email: "",
    emailRules: [
      (v) => !!v || "E-mail is required",
      (v) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || "E-mail must be valid",
    ],
    select: null,
    items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"],
    checkbox: false,
  }),

  methods: {
    login() {
      let formValidation = this.$refs.form.validate();
      console.log("formValidation", formValidation);

      if (formValidation) {
        this.$fire.auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
          .catch(function (error) {
            // that.snackbarText = error.message;
            // that.snackbar = true;
            console.log("login error", error.message);
            $nuxt.$router.push("/");
          })
          .then((user) => {
            // this.$fire.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            //   currentUser = user.uid;
            // });
            //we are signed in
            $nuxt.$router.push("/member/desk");
          });
      }
    },
    reset() {
      this.$refs.form.reset();
    },
    resetValidation() {
      this.$refs.form.resetValidation();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[image: user variable also coming as null]

**--- UPDATE ---**

After implementing "Firebase Auth with SSR(https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/tutorials/ssr#step-3---retrieve-the-server-user)" I managed to fix this to some extent. Now, when I refresh(normal reload) `"/member/desk" route` it's now working fine(staying at same page). But, when I'm doing HARD RELOAD it's redirecting to "/auth/signin" route.

I believe it's something related to that "Server Worker" implementation. On HARD RELOAD all cached data getting deleted & Service Worker restarted once again.

I maybe wrong also. Can anyone please give me some clarity!!!

Answer (score 1):

As said in firebase auth documentation here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) :

> firebase.auth().currentUser can also be null because the auth object
> has not completed initialization. If you use an observer to track the
> user's login status, you don't need to handle this case.

Which means that if your middleware is called too soon - when the auth.onStateChanged is not done yet - app.$fire.auth.currentUser will initially be null.

I suggest you to change your middleware by using the user stored in your Vuex.

```
export default function ({ store, app, route, redirect }) {
    const user = store.state.user;
    if (route.path === '/') {
        //leave them on the sign in page
    } else if (route.path !== '/auth/signin') {
        //we are on a protected route
        if (!user) {
            //take them to sign in page
            return redirect('/auth/signin')
            // return redirect('/auth/signout')
        }
    } else if (route.path === '/auth/signin') {
        if (!user) {
            //leave them on the sign in page
        } else {
            return redirect('/')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for ```user``` also I'm getting ```null```. Attached chrome dev tool screenshot. Maybe I'm missing something else.

Comment: It looks like your state is not persisted between hard reloads, you can use this package https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate or this one https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist to do that in your store configuration.
After that, your connected user will stay connected, and you will be able to pass the middleware check directly.

Comment: If you store the user like that, can't a maliscious user fiddle with the state in the browser and bypass middleware? Hence why it may be important to rely on auth.currentUser vs store.state.user

Comment: If your application is well coded, you have a JWT that is attached with every response and request ongoing. This JWT is encrypted with the data concerning your user. So if you try to change with some devtool user's data, the JWT will be invalid anyway and the request won't be completed.